# Calling a function with a return type other than void as a lone statement in Java

Tags: java

I've noticed that functions with return types like double, int, etc, can be called as statements like voids can. Like this:

```
int foo() { return 5; }
....
foo();
```

What is the meaning of this? Does it literally just execute the function and then discard the return value, thus the purpose would be creating functions that can act as voids and return-type functions for multi-purpose use?

Comment: Yes, and it's also used for method chaining.

Comment: is there really nothing else going on in foo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the return value is simply not used.

Answer (score 5):

Correct.

Java does not force you to use the return value when calling a function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes return value will be discarded.

You'll not be forced to use the value by compiler. But probably you should use that value.